# How to use Math.floor method for solving numbers

Tags: javascript

Values entered on input fields will split into 3 parts 30%, 30% 40% e.g. physics has values = 500 then values will be 150, 150, 200

How to do this part please help. I am new in JavaScript.

Comment: What have you tried so far to get the desired results? SO is not a free coding service. Please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1):

Math.floor method is used to round off the number passed as a parameter to its nearest integer in Downward direction of rounding i.e. towards the lesser value.

for ex:

input => `Math.floor(22.9)`
output => `22`

can you be more specific?

Comment: I need to split number into 3 parts 30% 30% 40%. For eg. when I input any number like I input 500  to the input field then it would immediately split 500  into three parts like 150 150 200

Answer (score 0):

You can multiple the number by 0.3 and 0.4 to get the required percentage. To get te floor or ceil you can do this:

Math.floor(num)
Math.ceil(num)

Answer (score 0):

```js
const inputValue = 500
const percentages = [30, 30, 40]

const result = percentages.map(percentage => Math.floor(inputValue * percentage / 100)).join(', ')

console.log(result)
```

Comment: How I can display result in the input field. Please help.